# cakephp js helper ajax: email id doesn't display name in input text box

Tags: cakephp, jquery

I have a form with input text box for email and input text box for name.

When the user enters his/her email id, automatically the correct name for that email id should be fetched and displayed (fr the database) in the name input text box using Ajax.

The following is my code but when i enter the email id and press the tab button, no name gets displayed (the way AJAX is supposed to work). Can someone point me out on where i'm going wrong? Thank you.

I'm trying to do this using Cakephp, jquery, and ajax.

Source code from browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {$("#MerryParentEmail").bind("keyup", function (event) 
{$.ajax({async:true, dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus)   
{$("#MerryParentName").html(data);}, type:"post", url:"\/merry_parents\/getname"});
    return false;});});
    //]]>
    </script>
```

view.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Form->create('MerryParent', array('default'=>false));

echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<legend>Parent Information</legend>';
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.email');
if (isset($name))
   echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.name', array('label'=>'Parent/Guardian Name','value'=>$name));
else
   echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.name', array('label'=>'Parent/Guardian Name'));

$this->Js->get('#MerryParentEmail');
$this->Js->event('keyup',
$this->Js->request(array(
'controller'=>'merry_parents',
        'action'=>'getname'),
            array('async'=>true,
                  'update'=>'#MerryParentName',
                  'method'=>'post')
     )
);

echo '</fieldset>';

echo $this->Form->end('Submit');

 ?>
```

merry_parents_controller.php

```
<?php
 class MerryParentsController extends AppController{
public $many_children_flag='false';
var $name='MerryParents';

function beforeFilter()//executed before any controller action logic
{   parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Security->validatePost=false;  //set to false to completely skip the validation of POST request
        //parent::beforeFilter();
    if(isset($this->Security) && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() && $this->action = 'getname'){
        $this->Security->enabled = false;
        $this->autoRender=false;
        }   
}

function getname(){
 if (!empty($this->data)){
    //var_dump($this->data);
    $merryparent_info=$this->MerryParent->getMerryParents($this->data['MerryParent']['email']);
    //print_r($merryparent_info);
    $name=$merryparent_info['MerryParent']['name'];
    $this->set('name',$name);
    //$this->render('/merry_parents/ajax_input');
    }
}
function view(){
    //$name='';
    //var_dump($this->data);
    //$this->getname();
}
```

merry_parent.php model

```
function getMerryParents($field_value){
    if (is_int($field_value))
        $conditions=array('merryParent.id'=>$field_value);
    else
        $conditions=array('merryParent.email'=>$field_value);

    //debug($conditions);

    $merryparent_info=$this->find('first',array(
                                'conditions'=>$conditions,
                                'recursive'=>-1   //fetches merry_parents table data only not the associated data
                                ));

    //debug($merryparent_info);
    return $merryparent_info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the data of the form back to your controller.
When binding the JS request to the keyup event you're entering javascript respectively jQuery through CakePHP proxy methods. And there is no autmatic binding to your form data, so you have to manage that on your own.

However there is a handy parameter in CakePHP for that! Try

```
$this->Js->get('#MerryParentEmail');
$this->Js->event('keyup',
$this->Js->request(array(
'controller'=>'merry_parents',
        'action'=>'getname'),
            array('async'=>true,
                  'update'=>'#MerryParentName',
                  'dataExpression'=>true,
                  'data'=>$this->Js->serializeForm(array('inline'=>true)),
                  'method'=>'post')
     )
);
```